# Linux Shell Script - Python libraries cannot be found after activating virtual environment through shell script from another directory

Tags: python, linux, shell

Situation:  I am trying to expose a repo I have through a flask app - it is all stored on the same linux server.  The flask app is within a folder called `var` which is on the same level as `home`.  I have a repo in `Documents` where I have created a virtual environment containing all necessary libraries, and when I run a shell script within this repo it works correctly.

Problem:  When I try to launch a shell script from my Python script in the flask application, I use the below code:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/Documents/my_repo \
source my_env/bin/activate \
th code/my_script.lua
python code/my_script2.py
```

When I execute this within `my_repo` this works with no problems and generates the desired results.  However, when I try to trigger this from my flask application it complains that I am missing modules.  I know that the modules are there because it works from within the folder, but it cannot find the modules.  The below comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/prediction_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model import G_NET, D_NET64, D_NET128, D_NET256, D_NET512, D_NET1024, INCEPTION_V3
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_repo/code/model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

where `code` is a folder in `my_repo`

When I get the current working directory when running my Python script it outputs the following: `/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_repo`

Question:  I have tried to ensure the I am in the repo's working directory by also changing directory before accessing my second script, but it still has the same missing module error.  What can I change to ensure that it can locate the correct libraries?

Comment: How about adding some output about your state? `pwd` comes to mind. And trying to do a `pip freeze` after activating the environment. Additionally I wonder why you don't want your first and second linebreaks?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Linux Shell". Please read the description of both the "shell" and "linux" tags that you applied. Also, put such keywords into the tags, not the topic.